# How do I fix a UWebBrowser not rendering anything in Unreal Engine UMG?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-umg

I'm having a really hard time creating a `UWebBrowser` and adding it to a `UCanvas` in C++.
I got an equivalent blueprint working perfectly by just dropping the `UWebBrowser` widget into the `UCanvas` widget.

The `UTextBlock` in my example renders perfectly, but the `UWebBrowser` doesn't render anything at all.
I've tried setting visibility & anchors, but it doesn't help.

How can I debug what's going on here?

```cpp
void UWalletWidget::NativeConstruct()
{
    Super::NativeConstruct();
    auto Canvas = WidgetTree->ConstructWidget<UCanvasPanel>(UCanvasPanel::StaticClass());
    WidgetTree->RootWidget = canvas;

    auto WebWidget = WidgetTree->ConstructWidget<UWebBrowser>(UWebBrowser::StaticClass());
    canvas->AddChildToCanvas(WebWidget);
    WebWidget->LoadUrl("https://google.ca/")

    auto TextWidget = WidgetTree->ConstructWidget<UTextBlock>(UTextBlock::StaticClass());
    canvas->AddChildToCanvas(TextWidget);
    TextWidget->Text = FText::FromString(TEXT("Testing text!"));
}
```